# can't append text to string array due to Initializer for conditional binding error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, append

My code below works perfectly if i switch the strings for the ints. However with the String where it is it is not working.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var txt: UITextField!
var arrayOfInt = [String]()

@IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any) {
    if let text = txt.text {
    if let name = String(text){
        arrayOfInt.append(name)
    }}}

}
```

Comment: `if let text = txt.text {
    if let name = String(text!){
        arrayOfInt.append(name)
    }}}`

Comment: Why are you naming an array go strings `arrayOfInt`?

Comment: This is confusing overall, but 1) There's no reason to use String with a variable that is already a string and 2) I think ahmed's comment may not be correct since the "text" variable is already unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

You are (unnecessarily) initialising a `String` from a `String` using `String(text)`; Unlike `Int(_ string:String)` this is not a *failable initializer*.

It is possible that a `String` cannot be parsed to an `Int`, so you need to check that `Int(text)` didn't return `nil`, but a `String` can always be initialised from a `String`.

When you say

```
if let name = String(text) {
```

The compiler give you an error because the `if let...` conditional binding construct requires an optional, but `String(text)` does not return an optional.

Your code can be simplified to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var txt: UITextField!
    var arrayOfString = [String]()

    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any) {
        if let text = sender.text {
            arrayOfString.append(text)
        }
    }
}
```